# Integration of Big Query and Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-bigquery

I have a view in BQ. What I need is to handle manual overrides which sometimes might be applied to the view. Is there a way to keep the data from BQ saved in Google Sheets as well to be able to edit data there? It would be like: Big Query => Google Sheets => Big Query data flow.

Is there any other smart and efficient way to handle the problem?

Comment: Could you provide a more specific example of an "override applied to the view"? It's possible to query Google Sheets from BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-drive but I'm not sure if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have some (small) tables that you want to occasionally edit by hand to fix up your existing data.

So:

- Large table stored in BigQuery.
- View over large table.
- Small table of overrides for the view (kept in Sheets).
- Query output (kept in Sheets).

As Tim mentions, if you create  a federated table, you can use that as both input or output for a query.

So that all sounds pretty reasonable. Another option you might consider is embedding the overrides directly into the view (either as a JOIN against literal values or a CASE statement). That may execute more quickly, but might be less convenient to edit if you need to do that frequently.